# Notebook inbuilt keyboard stopped working

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

After Upgrading packages `console-setup` `console-setup-linux` `keyboard-configuration` my notebook inbuilt keyboard stopped responding to any action/key press . I can able to use USB external but inbuilt keyboard not working but inbuilt keyboard works if i do live boot and with other OS or distribution of linux . I have followed all Keyboard debugging detection checked along with `dmesg` and the log `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and found keyboard connected . This behavior is very strange to me

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep 'XINPUT'   
[    43.824] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    43.840] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    43.856] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    43.904] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "VGA WebCam: VGA WebCam" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    43.956] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ELAN0501:00 04F3:3060 Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 10)
[    43.980] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    44.004] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Acer WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[ 18853.582] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
```

few other parts of log ::

```
[ 18853.362] (II) config/udev: Adding input device C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE (/dev/input/event14)
[ 18853.494] (**) C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 18853.505] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE'
[ 18853.505] (**) C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE: always reports core events
[ 18853.505] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event14"
[ 18853.506] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 18853.548] (II) event14 - C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 18853.548] (II) event14 - C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE: device is a keyboard
[ 18853.548] (II) event14 - C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE: device removed
[ 18853.582] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input16/event14"
[ 18853.582] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[ 18853.582] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 18853.583] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 18853.583] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[ 18853.583] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[ 18853.626] (II) event14 - C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 18853.626] (II) event14 - C8:F2:30:D1:57:CE: device is a keyboard
```

Comment: Have you rebooted?